# How do I app.Invoke backdoor method with multiple parameters? At runtime I'm getting System.Exception: "No such method found"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

Xamarin.Forms, android project, inside MainActivity:

```
[Java.Interop.Export("BackDoorMethod")]
private void BackDoorMethod(int param1, int param2, int param3)
{
    // some code here
}
```

Code to call that method from Xamarin.Uitest project:

```
app.Invoke("BackDoorMethod", new object[] { 30, 50, 15 }); // causes exception at runtime
```

Here is StackTrace:

```
System.Exception: Error while performing Invoke("BackDoorMethod", [ 30, 50, 15 ]) ---> System.Exception: Invoke for BackDoorMethod failed with outcome: ERROR
No such method found: BackDoorMethod([Integer], [Integer], [Integer])
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidGestures.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] arguments) [0x0008d] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp+<>c__DisplayClass89_0.<Invoke>b__0 () [0x00000] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x0000e] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x0005b] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0
  at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object[] arguments) [0x0001b] in <a0c3f09cbf9049cbb8d3a680a53dcf46>:0
  at ProjectName.PageTests.TestClass.TestMethod (System.Int32 param1) [0x00037] in /Users/UserName/Projects/SolutionName/Tests/ProjectName.PageTests.TestClass.cs:124
```

Attempt to do data type casting like `app.Invoke( ... (object)30, (object)50, ...` doesn't change anything.

Changing method declaration from 3 parameters of type `int` to 3 parameters of type `object` or single parameter of type `object[]` give compilation error.

Some research led me to info about that Java has data type `int`, which is value type and `Integer`, which is reference type, which probably might be the reason for this problem, but C# shouldn't have any problems converting `Int32` to `object` and vice versa. So how can I make it work properly?

P.S. Same approach with single parameter of type `int` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On Android, IApp.Invoke can be used to invoke a method in the Xamarin.Android application according to the following rules:
>
> - The method must be **public**.
>
> ...

([From the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/working-with-backdoors), emphasis mine)

Your method is declared as a `private` method. Should work after making it `public`.

Comment: @ConstantineKetskalo Glad I could help ;)